# Are children widets always shown after parent and hidden before parent when show()/hide() is called on the parent widget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a `QWidget` that contains a few other `QWidget`s.

When I hide the parent, its `hideEvent` is always called after the visible child's is called.

Is there a way to enforce a strict ordering that children are always shown after the parent and parent is always all children are hidden?